# structure in C using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

i can't understand the output that give by my code which use with pointers. 
can anyone help me with this

here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    struct stype {
        int x;
        char *p;
    };

    struct stype s[ ] = {
                        { 1 , "Colombo" },
                        { 2 , "Gampaha" },
                        { 3 , "Kalutara" },
                        { 4 , "Matara" },
                        { 5 , "Galle" },
                        };
    struct stype *t;

    t = s;
    t++;

    printf( "%d\n" , t->x );
    printf( "%c\n", *( ++t->p ) );
    printf( "%s\n" , t->p );
    printf( "%d\n" , ( ++t )->x );
    printf( "%s\n", ++t->p );
    printf( "%s\n" , ++t->p );
    printf( "%c\n" , *( ++t->p ) + 5 );

}
```

Here is the output i get

```
2
a
ampaha
3
alutara
lutara
z
```

Comment: Which part specifically you have problem understanding?

Comment: Unless you are on a non-conforming embedded system, `void main()` is an invalid program startup. See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [See What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: @SouravGhosh  *( ++t->p ) and ++t->p what happen with these two?

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a problem designed to introduce you to [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- I think that some versions of Microsoft (non-conforming) C allow `void main()` as a signature.

Comment: @PasinduSenarath `'->'` has *Precedence 1* while `++` has *Precedence 2*. `'->'` is applied before `++` in `*(++t->p)` and `++t->p`

Comment: @DavidBowling - yes, that's a hangover from the DOS 3.3 days and Borland TurboC++ -- but that doesn't mean you should still use it (or at least know it is non-conforming).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The link you've provided says that `main` can be defined "in some other implementation-defined manner", as does cppref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Comment: @bipll - that is correct, the standard speaks in terms of *"or in some other implementation-defined manner"*, i.e. non-conforming manner. If the implementation were conforming, then program startup would defined by **5.1.2.2.1**.

Comment: Humm, so your point is that if an implementation defines something in a way the Standard explicitly allows it to, it is non-comformant, or what? It is non-consistent with a particular phrase of the Standard, but completely agrees with another, which makes it Standard-conforming from my point of view. 0_o Note that 5.1.2.2.1 is an alternative list that is completely-exhausting in the sense that it ends in "or whatever".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is given line by line below

```
struct stype *t ;                  // t is a pointer to struct
t = s ;                            // t will point to the array
t++;                               // increment t, so it will point to the 
                                   //  first element i.e. s[1] 
printf( "%d\n" , t->x ) ;          // print s[1].x i.e 2
printf( "%c\n", *( ++t->p ) ) ;    // Here the precedence rules come into play. 
                                   // The Prefix increment is in level 2 and -> operator 
                                   // is in level 1, so -> operator will be carried out first   
                                   // and then ++, t-> p will point to  "Gampaha"   
                                   // and incrementing that will point 
                                   // to the next character "ampaha" 
                                   // so *(++t->p) will give 'a'
printf( "%s\n" , t->p ) ;          // t->p is already incremented, 
                                   // so it will point to "ampaha". 
printf( "%d\n" , ( ++t )->x ) ;    // t is incremented to point to s[2] 
                                   // and x, of that is taken, so will print 3
printf( "%s\n", ++t->p ) ;         // t-> p is first executed, "Kalutara",  
                                   // t->p is incremented so, "alurata" is printed.
printf( "%s\n" , ++t->p ) ;        // again t-> p is first executed, "alutara",  
                                   // t->p is incremented so, "lurata" is printed.
printf( "%c\n" , *( ++t->p ) + 5 ) ;   // t-> p is first executed "lutara", 
                                       // t-> p is incremented "utra" *( ++t->p ) is 'u' 
                                       // and 5 is added to that to get 'z'
```

Comment: "Since -> and ++ operator are in the same level" -- wrong. That only applies to *Post-Increment*, not *Pre-Increment*. Pre-Increment is Level 2. No dings for it, but it needs fixing. Also, explanations in comments that spill off the side of the page are not as helpful as tidy paragraphs explaining the same thing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Exactly. Also The associativity is checked from left to right for level 2

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Pre increment is level 3 and arrow is level 2

Comment: @VidorVistrom - see: [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 0):

I think u had problem in understanding the `printf( "%c\n" , *( ++t->p ) + 5 );` is it right?

```
*( ++t->p ) = u
```

ascii value of u is 117.

117+5 = 122

ascii value of z is 122.

so,the output is z.